# What are the purposes of other members of a Singleton class besides the instance and its get method?

Tags: design-patterns, singleton, gang-of-four

From Design Pattern by GoF

> [image]
>
> **Participants**
>
> •  `Singleton`
>
> - defines an `Instance` operation that lets clients access its unique instance `uniqueinstance`. `Instance` is a class operation (that is, a class method in
>     Smalltalk and a static member function in C++).
> - may be responsible  for creating its own unique  instance `uniqueinstance`.
>
> **Collaborations**
>
> •  Clients access a `Singleton` instance `uniqueinstance` solely through `Singleton`'s
>   `Instance` operation.

In Class `Singleton`, `uniqueinstance` is the unique instance, and `Instance()` is its get method.

What are the purposes of the other members:

- method `SingletonOperation()`,
- method `GetSingletonData()`, and
- field `singletonData`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing in particular, or rather say it has nothing to do with `Singleton` , you can just remove it or rename it or whatever you like. It's just a normal method and has nothing to do to your class being a **Singleton**.

Comment: On the other hand, if the book did not show the additional methods and field, then readers might wonder if singletons are allowed to have instance methods and fields.

Comment: @jaco0646 you have a point, but they could just have named it in a different way, so that they won't confuse anyone e.g.(myMethod(), or whatever).

Answer (score 1):

The additional methods and field in the diagram show that singletons are allowed to include state and behavior; i.e. singletons are not just constants. Furthermore, singletons are intended for subclassing, a feature which is often overlooked, despite the GoF mentioning it several times.

> Use the Singleton pattern when... the sole instance should be extensible by subclassing, and clients should be able to use an extended instance without modifying their code.

So the additional methods are also shown to indicate that singletons may be polymorphic.

> The Singleton class
>   may be subclassed, and it's easy to configure an application with an instance
>   of this extended class. You can configure the application with an instance
>   of the class you need at run-time.

The book goes on to describe multiple ways in which this configuration may be achieved.