# Why does the builder pattern not have a method `GetResult()` in the builder interface?

Tags: design-patterns, builder, gang-of-four

From Design Pattern by Gang of Four,
[image]

Example:

[image]

Why doesn't the interface `Builder` have a method `GetResult()`, which is overridden in the concrete class `ConcreteBuilder`?

In the example, the concrete builders have `GetXXX()` methods, where `XXX` is different for different concrete builders, which doesn't promote "programming to interface" at all.

Is this "omission" deliberate in the builder pattern?

Comment: Only thing that comes to mind immediately is that since there weren't generics back then the thing that came back would always have to be cast anyway, which makes an interface method not as useful. A `BuiltThing` interface on its own probably isn't super-useful

Comment: The book was written in C++ not Java. C++ had template then.

Comment: `GetResult` is the function related to ConcreteBuilder. The name here is deceiving. There can be another builder `WoodBuilder` that may have its own function `Manufacture()`.

Comment: @Tim Okay, but as a general pattern, I'm still not sure an "interface" method would be helpful. ¯\(°_o)/¯

Comment: @Arun The builder should return the result in some way, so it's not unreasonable to expect a method which would return the result in the `Builder` interface.

Comment: @DaveNewton Even without generics all "things" could implement some common interface. If "parts" are abstract enough to be represented via obviously useful `BuildPart()` method in the interface, I don't see why a common `BuildThing` can't be useful to represent "things".

But, still, this is the best explanating so far.

Comment: @lexicore Thanks. Besides "omission", the book sometimes has some unexpected "addition". See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46480156/what-are-the-purposes-of-other-members-of-a-singleton-class-besides-the-instance

Comment: @lexicore I think what I mean is that in a specific system you'd probably want a `BuiltThing` interface, e.g., if you're returning UI elements that have some similarity. Then you'd have a class living between the interface and the system that implements that system-/usage-specific interface. I'm not sure, really.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the omission is deliberate. The book addresses it directly.

> *Why no abstract class for products?* In the common case, the products produced
>   by the concrete builders differ so greatly in their representation that
>   there is little to gain from giving different products a common parent class. Because the client usually
>   configures the director with the proper concrete builder, the client is
>   in a position to know which concrete subclass of Builder is in use and can
>   handle its products accordingly.

Regarding the comments to the OP, generics could assist the client in handling products by enabling a `GetResult()` method with a generic return type in the `Builder` interface.