# Why do some methods belong to the subject/observer interface, while others to the subject/observer concrete subclass?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, observer-pattern, gang-of-four

From Design Pattern by Gang of Four
[image]

Why are field `observers`, and methods `Attach`, `Detach` and `Notify` are in the interface `Subject`, while methods `GetState` and `SetState` and field  `SubjectState` are in the concrete subclass `ConcreteSubject`? Why are the members distributed in the subject interface and concrete subclass as they are?

Why is  method `Update` in the interface `Observer`, while fields `subject` and `observerState` in the concrete subclass `ConcreteObserver`?
Why are the members distributed in the observer interface and concrete subclass  as they are?

There doesn't seem to be symmetry between subject and observer.
For example, why does field `observers` belong to interface `Subject`, while field `subject` belong to `ConcreteObserver`?

Thanks.

Comment: I think this is effectively the same question as https://stackoverflow.com/q/46495698/3001761; the patterns are general, they don’t make the assumption that the implementing language will have generic typing. So the gets and sets are on the concrete classes where the type is known.

Comment: None of this is true in Java.

Comment: What is it like in java?@EJP

Comment: @Tim It's documented. I see no reason to reproduce any of that here. The real question is why did you tag this with [tag:java] when you didn't know what you were talking about?

Answer (score 1):

The method GetState and SetState in the Subject interface would make Subject interface dependent on how the dependent objects are updated. This is a violation of Dependency Inversion principle.

All Subject interface does is attach a concrete subject and notifies the observer. How the states of the concrete objects are changing it is independent of that. This is the reason why getState and setState not part of the Subject Interface.

Similar reason why observeState is not part of Observer interface.

Comment: Thanks. why does field `observers` belong to interface `Subject`, while field `subject` belong to the concrete `ConcreteObserver`?

Comment: Association with Observer interface belongs to subject. Which is correct. This is to get the observer list. Here Subject knows who are observing the subjects and A concrete observer knows what subject I am observing.

Answer (score 1):

This is an Observer Design pattern. All the GOF patterns will use OO principles to maximum extent. If the responsibilities (and state) are common in many child classes those need to be escalated in the base class hierarchy to the uppermost possible layer. Following demo code and comments will answer the above questions.
Its true that some of the design patterns (and Observer is one of those. see the type casting in update()) violate the OO principles. ***Its perfectly fine to violate these principles only one needs to know which principle and why we are violating***. and check - *are we getting more benefit than the probable inflexibility/ damage introduced in to the implementation?*

```
    public interface Observer {
        /**
          * IF THIS METHOD IS NOT HERE SUBJECT WILL NOT BE ABLE TO CALL IT
          * REFER TO OO BASICS - INHERITANCE
          */
        void update(Subject subject);
    }

    public abstract class Subject {
        // THE COMPLETE LOGIC HERE IS INDEPENDENT OF 
        // WHO THE CONCRETE SUBJECT IS.
        // HENCE THIS IS A RIGHT PLACE FOR IT AS PER OO PRINCIPLES
        // NOTE THAT THIS CLASS KNOWS ONLY ABOUT ABSTRACT OBSERVER
        private Set<Observer> observers; 
        public void add(Observer o){/*...*/}
        public void remove(Observer o){/*...*/}
        protected void notifyAllObservers(){
            for (Observer observer : observers) {
                observer.update(this);
            }
        }
    }

    class ConcreteSubject extends Subject {
        /**
         * HERE THERE IS NO NEED TO KNOW THE CONCRETE OBSERVER-
         * By DEFINITION OF THIS PATTERN. 
         * THE JOB HERE IS TO ONLY NOTIFY ALL OBSERVERS THAT "I HAVE CHANGED"
         * ITS OBSERVER'S RESPONSIBILITY TO REACT IN PULL METHOD
         */

         // Concrete Subject state
         // Concrete Subject behavior
        public void specificMethod(){
            //... concrete class specific logic
        }
    }

    class ConcreteObserver implements Observer{
        @Override
        public void update(Subject subject) {
            /**
             * OBSERVE HERE WE NEED TO TYPE CAST, WHICH LEADS TO VIOLATION OF 
             * OO PRINCIPLES. BUT WE GET BENEFIT OF LOOSELY COUPLED OBSERVERS
             * AGAINST THIS EXTRA COST
             * ITS SAFE TO VIOLATE HERE AS OBSERVER INSTANCES MAKE ONLY 
             * SENSE IN CONTEXT WITH SUBJECT AND WILL NEVER BE REUSED AS
             * OBSERVERS IN UNRELATED CONTEXT.
             */
            ((ConcreteSubject)subject).specificMethod();
        }
    }
```